# How to compare date in linux for specific format

Tags: linux, perl

I want to compare date 08-08-2018 and 20-07-2018.

```
if (dt1 > $ dt2){
Success
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: "Linux" isn't a programming language. Are you writing a shell script? Please tag your question appropriately, and show actual code for what you have so far.

Comment: In Perl script I have to compare date.Is there any comparison operator for specific date format in Linux.
Thanks.

Comment: Ok hymie. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your date formats are static, you have two easy options.

Option 1

1. Strip out the day, month, and year from each date.
2. Compare the two years.
3. If the years are the same, compare the two months.
4. If the months are the same, compare the two days.

Option 2

1. Strip out the day, month, and year from each date.
2. Create a new date string in the YYYY-MM-DD format
3. Do a standard string comparison on the two resulting strings.

I'm sorry, but I'm not in a position to provide you with sample code at this time.

Comment: Thank you so much, For suggestion. I followed Option2

Answer (score 5):

The core
[`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module
allows you to convert a date/time string to an object using the `strptime` class method. The resulting objects can be compared using the standard `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, and `==` operators as you describe, and being a core module it is unlikely to need installing

Here's a short program that uses the values in your question, converts them to `Time::Piece` objects `$dt1` and `$dt2`, and compares them as you describe

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my ($dt1, $dt2) = map { Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%d-%m-%Y') } qw/ 08-08-2018 20-07-2018 /;

if ( $dt1 > $dt2 ) {
    say 'Success';
}
else {
    say 'Failure';
}
```

#### output

```
Success
```